# Duplicity spell

Tags: dnd-5e

When using duplicate shouldn’t there be a disadvantage to incoming attacks when your duplicate is in both opponent and your melee? Could you disengage without the bonus action if your duplicate stayed in place after attacking melee/melee spell?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! As it is, you're asking several questions at once, and many of them aren't suitable to the site's format. Take a look at the guides for good questions and try to formulate your doubt more clearly.

Comment: Are you referring to the Trickery Domain cleric, or something else?

Comment: I'm very unclear on what's being asked here. Can you edit to specify where the terms are coming from (i.e. the spell 'duplicate', the class feature 'duplicity').?

Comment: Or perhaps, a spell to summon Julia Roberts and Clive Owen?

Comment: Why do you think you can "disengage with a bonus action" in the first place? That's a rogue feature - normally it requires an action to disengage.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Once you edit your question to clarify what you're asking, we can hopefully reopen it and help answer it.

Answer (score 3):

### Rules as Written

There is no spell called "Duplicity" or "Duplicate", so I'm going out on a limb and presuming you mean the *Trickery Cleric* ability *[Channel Divinity: Invoke Duplicity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#TrickeryDomain)*, which does the following:

- Created as an action within 30' of the character.
- Requires concentration.
- Moved 30' (to a max distance of 120') as a bonus action.
- Can cast spells as if you were standing where the duplicate is.
- Grants advantage on attack rolls when character and duplicate are within 5' of the same target.

### Your Specific Questions

The ability only does what it says, nothing more. It already does a whole lot, and you're proposing to make it even better.

- It doesn't impose disadvantage on incoming attacks. Being [invisible](https://www.dndbeyond.com/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#invisible) does, which is a feature of a 2nd level (or higher) spells, some very high-end magic items, and the Trickery Cleric's own sixth level *Channel Divinity: Cloak of Shadows*. Seeing the same person twice may be mildly confusing, but it's clearly not better than not being able to see the person at all.
- It doesn't allow disengaging as a bonus action. That's an ability [Rogues](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue) get via *Cunning Action* at L2. Why should a cleric get all that Invoke Duplicity already does *plus* an a ability Rogues get?

*Could* a DM allow it to do these extra things? Sure.

*Should* a DM allow it to do these extra things? No, because it cheapens other classes and later spells and abilities.